# Пользовательский выбор точек на графике

Tags: python, python-3.x

столкнулся со следующей проблемой: есть некоторое облако точек, находящееся в одной плоскости. Необходимо визуализировать его и кликая мышкой по точкам, иметь возможность добавлять/удалять их из списка. Возможно кто-то может посоветовать библиотеку, которая позволяет это сделать адекватно, или какую-то литературу, которая может натолкнуть на мысли, как это сделать. Количество точек обычно около 200-500к.

Comment: А в чем сложность, если не учитывать непомерное количество?

Comment: 500000 точек на экране? Вы надеетесь увидеть еще одну точку? Или попасть в конкретную точку? Попробуйте нарисовать такое количество точек, а потом найти (попасть) в конкретную.

Comment: @MBo Проблема в том, что я в целом не понимаю, как это сделать, если честно. День посидел покурил интернет, но не нашел ничего вменяемого:(

Comment: @passant точки достаточно сильно разбросаны, плюс масштабирование вида можно сделать. но опять же, вопрос был не об этом)

Comment: В средах/языках со встроенными развитыми средствами построения интерфейса, как Шарп или Дельфи, отображение точек, регистрация точки  клика, делается за минуты. Соотнесение координат с ближайшей точкой от языка не зависит, при малом количестве точек это простой поиск, при большом можно построить диаграмму Вороного. Для начала посмотрите, какие библиотеки в питоне могут отображать простую графику и регистрировать события мыши

Comment: Попробуйте использовать библиотеку plotly. Вот тут меняют отображение точек клкая по ним https://plotly.com/python/click-events/